# SVN : "Authentication failed" for clone of a repository

Tags: windows, svn

I have a repository A (working fine).
I created a dump of A:
svnadmin dump /the/path/to/A > old-repo.dump

Loaded to another repositor B:

svnadmin load /the/path/to/B < old-repo.dump

When I commit changes, Using same username and password for repository B it is showing "Authentication failed".

My target : create a clone of existing repository with same user access.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried VisualSVN Server? Asking this since you are on Windows. Besides that, show us your `svnserve`'s config and log.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I resolved it, in svnserve.conf I forgot to un-comment "password-db = passwd".